# mysql replication insert only

Tags: mysql

I have several slave dbs replicated from the same master db, however, for one of the slaves, i would like to keep it as a backup db, which will never have rows updated or deleted.

basically the purpose is to have a backup db with all rows stored by using the replication(mysqldump is waaay slow to do the backup), no update/delete query get replicated, insert query only. i know there will be some conflicts going on no doubt, but still wonder if any filtering options on statement/query on the slave end or any other solutions.

Comment: Insufficient information for useful answer. It's not clear what you want to do. "I know there will be some conflicts" - how can there be conflicts if there are no local writes? This question is currently unclear and inconsistent, please clarify it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** run a production database without a working backup scheme in place - at least as long as you value your data. If you fear that a wrong sql instruction can ruin your database, then you may try *point in time recovery*.

If you already use replication your master server will log all write/update operations to its binlog - which it will send to the slave servers for replication. You can do for example nightly backups of you complete database. If you destroy your database in the morning, you can import the backup from the night and reapply the instructions from the binlog from after the backup till before the instruction that killed your database.

You could then skip this instruction and apply the instructions that came afterwards. This can also cause consistency issues, as the instruction after the skipped instruction see different data in the database as they did when they were originally executed.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem. I know it's old thread but it can help others:

link: [mysql replication works only if I choose database by USE database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989768/mysql-replication-works-only-if-i-choose-database-by-use-database)